# Why is it possible to use BT.709 in H.264 to represent more colors than BT.601?

Tags: h.264, yuv

Why is it possible to use BT.709 in H.264 to represent more colors than BT.601? I think that for YUV, they are all only Y, U, and V data. When converting to RGB, only different matrices are used. Using different matrices may cause U to become more V and less. BT.709 It is not possible to indicate more colors than BT.601. Or there is a color that BT.709 cannot represent but BT.601 can represent.Can anyone tell me where the mistake is.

Comment: The reason is that when RGB is converted to YUV, it will be truncated because it is out of range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

601, and 709 can display the same number of colors. 601s colors tend to map better to what a CRT can actually display, where as 709 maps to LCD. However 601 more commonly uses partial range, meaning each byte is encoded using the range 16-235, where as it is common to use full range with 709 (0-255). This is because partial range leaves padding at the extremes for analog distribution. Since the broadcast TV digital switch over happened in the US around the same time as everybody change from CRT to LCD the range/space tend to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

DVD used SMPTE 170M a.k.a. SMPTE C (SMPTE C uses D65 white point) primaries, while BT.601 matrix was derived from ITU-R Rec. BT.470 System M a.k.a. NTSC 1953 primaries and white point (that is Illuminant C and not D65 as the white point). (PAL DVD used BT.601 matrix too and so is JPEG, that defaults to BT.709 primaires.) What that means there is a mismatch between primaries and white point and matrix, while there should be none for optimal use of codepoints. So when new matrix was derived from BT.709 and even newer for BT.2020 primaires, it was more suitable. The conversion from primaries and white points to get two values that define YCbCr matrix is specified in ITU-T Rec. H.273.

What is also a problem is that BT.709 primaries are what is de facto standard for SDR displays, even with WCG one must to limit to BT.709 (that is done in Natural mode on galaxy devices and iPhones and LG TVs). But after decoding BT.601 content you will have SMPTE C or PAL primaries, that MUST be color managed to BT.709 primaries, that also introduces some loss.